# more_like_this elasticsearch query of multiple indices

Tags: python, elasticsearch, morelikethis

Is it possible to query multiple elasticsearch indices simultaneously when  searching with a `more_like_this` query?

I am constructing my queries in python, but I do not believe it matters. Here is the body for calling a single index:

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "Title",
        "Description"
      ],
      "like": {
        "_id": "62546841",
        "_index": "puppies",
        "_type": "puppies_little"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and here is the curl call:

```
 curl -XPOST http://machineName:9200/puppies/_search?pretty=true -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is not much to do to make this query work across multiple indices. I simply need to add the additional indices to the http call. For example, using curl:

```
curl -XPOST http://machineName:9200/puppies,kittens/_search?pretty=true -d '{ "query" : {  "more_like_this" : { "fields" : ["Title","Description"], "like" : { "_index" : "puppies", "_type":"puppies_little","_id":"62546841"} } } }'
```

Comment: So you just use a comma separated list if indexes “puppies,kittens,chicks” etc? Could you find any docs on this?